# Angular 4 Reactive form Validation for dynamic forms inside *ngFor with with dynamic name

Tags: forms, angular, validation

I have a page with repeated rows and each row having repeated forms like,

```
<div *ngFor="let item of taskListObj">
<form name="editForm_{{item.id}}">
 <input name="taskNme" value="{{item.name}}" type="text">
  ....
  .....
 <input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

How to validate each form using reactive forms, since form names are dynamic.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Iteration index
2. Put index to input name

e.g.

`<div *ngFor="let item of taskListObj; let i = index">
<input name="taskNme" value="{{item.name + i}}" type="text">`

Comment: Thanks. But how define this inside component

Comment: <input name="taskName" ...
    value="{{item.name + i}}"
    (Change)="onTaskNameChange(item, i)"
/>